# How to automate file move between OneDrive and applications.com.Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macos, applescript

I have been coding a database on Excel, recently had to support Mac, Office 2016 and onwards really doesn't support inline code, so I have had to borrow a Mac.

I want to make a 'patch' .app that when run on the end users computer will put the AppleScripts in the file which Microsoft has said it has to be.

I am able to detect if the folders exist and create them if needed. I am able to move files around on command using the desktop and documents directories, but if i use the onedrive directory (where the file is executed from) it does not work.

I've tried a few different code structures, I am a Windows user, so I am dealing with learning the operating system.

I have tried duplicate with and without replacing, copy, typing out the directory in vs. using files, vs. file or items and every.

This is my code right now, pretty much grabs the location of the script that is being run, then takes away the name of the app and adds the correct directory of the other scripts.

Checks if the folders exist and if not creates them.

Then is meant to move all the files in the source to the destination.

```
set Source to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::") & "AppleScripts/"
set ParentDestination to ("/Library/Application Scripts/")
set Destination to ("/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel/")
set ParentFound to false
set DestinationFound to false

tell application "System Events"
    if exists folder ParentDestination then 
        set ParentFound to true 
        if exists folder Destination then       
            set DestinationFound to true        
        end if  
    end if
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    if ParentFound = false then 
        make new folder at folder "Library" of startup disk with properties {name:"Application Scripts"}    
    end if
    if DestinationFound = false then    
        make new folder at folder "Application Scripts" of folder "Library" of startup disk with properties {name:"com.microsoft.Excel"}    
    end if
    duplicate (every item in Source) to Destination
end tell
```

The current error I have is: `Finder got an error: Handler can’t handle objects of this class.`

This varies depending on the code variations I try, but it is always on the moving of all files.

I know this is probably a simple thing, but I haven't even gotten on to getting Excel to call the code yet so I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

The Finder is touchy about file specifiers; that's why I always prefer to use System Events. But System Events doesn't have a functional 'duplicate' command, so... The following should work for local copies (at any rate, it does on my machine):

```
set Source to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::") & "AppleScripts/"
set libraryFolder to "~/Library"

tell application "System Events"
    if exists folder "Application Scripts" of folder libraryFolder then
        set AppScriptsFolder to folder "Application Scripts" of folder libraryFolder
    else
        set AppScriptsFolder to make new folder at folder libraryFolder with properties {name:"Application Scripts"}
    end if
    if exists folder "com.microsoft.Excel" of AppScriptsFolder then
        set targetFolder to folder "com.microsoft.Excel" of AppScriptsFolder
    else
        set targetFolder to make new folder at AppScriptsFolder with properties {name:"com.microsoft.Excel"}
    end if
    set targetFolder to (path of targetFolder) as alias
    set Source to (path of folder Source) as alias
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    duplicate (every item in Source) to targetFolder
end tell
```

I sincerely doubt you can run an AppleScript from a cloud directory. I mean, I've never tried to myself, and I don't have access to OneDrive to test it, but being able to run arbitrary code from a remote drive seems like a security nightmare. I'd be curious to know if you can manage it.